# Как передать заполненную таблицу в контроллер с помощью @Html.BeginFor()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Есть ViewModel, где есть коллекция `IQueryable<Monit10Learner> Monit10Learnes`:

**Monit10ElListVM.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class Monit10ElListVM
    {      
        public IQueryable<Monit10Learner> Monit10Learnes { get; set; }              
    }
}
```

По этой коллекции строиться таблица во View

**EditElList.cshtml**

```
@using WebApplication1.ViewModels;
@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.Monit10ElListVM

...

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    int rowNumber = 0;

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" cols="6" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">
        <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
            <th align="center"> № п/п </th>
            <th width="20%"> Фамилия </th>
            <th width="18%"> Имя </th>
            <th width="14%"> Отчество </th>
            <th width="12%"> Класс </th>
            <th width="14%"> % выполнения элемента содержания по КИМ ОГЭ-2015</th>
            <th width="14%"> Коррекционная оценка</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach(var item in Model.Monit10Learnes)        
        {
            rowNumber++;
            <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
                <td align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => rowNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x =>item.Surname)
                </td>                    
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)                    
                </td>                    
                <td>                     
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x =>item.SecondName)
                </td>                    
                <td align="center">      
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x =>item.ClassName)
                </td>                    
                <td align="center">      
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x =>item.ValueOge15)
                </td>                    
                <td align="center">      
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => item.RatingValue)                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-0">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо, чтобы пользователь заполнил поле `Коррекционная оценка`, т.е. `RatingValue` для каждой строки и получить эту коллекцию-`Monit10Learnes` в контроллере.

Если сейчас нажать на "Сохранить", то контроллер получает пустую модель и соответственно `Monit10Learnes` тоже пуст:

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditElLearn(Monit10ElListVM viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {            
            foreach (var v in viewModel.Monit10Learnes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.RatingValue);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код генерирует на странице несколько одинаковых текстбоксов с именем `item.RatingValue`. Т.е. на сервер приходит всего одно значение рейтинга, и даже его байндер никак не сможет сопоставить с конкретным свойством модели.

Байндер ожидает имена пришедших значений в формате `Monit10Learnes[0].RatingValue`, `Monit10Learnes[1].RatingValue`... Самый простой способ их получить - заменить `foreach` на `for` следующего вида:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Monit10Learnes.Count; i++)
{
    <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Monit10Learnes[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Monit10Learnes[i].RatingValue)
        </td>
    </tr>                
}
```

Или можно явно прописать имя контрола:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => item.RatingValue, templateName: null, htmlFieldName: "Monit10Learnes[" + (rowNumber - 1) + "].RatingValue")
```

Для того, чтобы все заработало, вам придется еще поменять тип свойства `Monit10Learnes` c `IQueryable<Monit10Learner>` на `List<Monit10Learner>` - байндеру нужен конкретный тип, который он может создать. При попытке создать интерфейс он упадет с ошибкой.

Comment: спасибо огромное, Вы мне очень помогли. Есть ли предложение как выравнять названия заголовков столбцов по горизонтали? Вроде установил `align="center"`

Comment: @adamshakhabov нет. я в верстке не слишком разбираюсь. задайте отдельным вопросом, приведя готовый html (скопируйте из кода страницы) - вам кто-нибудь ответит